# Operate on multiple columns at once

Tags: r

What is the programmatic way to operate on multiple columns (or rows) at a time? Consider the example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 5:14, c = 10:1, d = 14:5)
```

I'd like to create two new columns that contain the ratio of a/b and c/d. For simplicity sake, let's assume that the spatial relationship between all of the columns is consistent. With only two columns to make, one might as well do something like this:

```
df2$ab <- with(df2, a/b)
df2$cd <- with(df2, c/d)
```

or

```
df2 <- transform(df2, ab = a/b, cd = c/d)
```

To create a final product like:

```
    a  b  c  d        ab        cd
1   1  5 10 14 0.2000000 0.7142857
2   2  6  9 13 0.3333333 0.6923077
3   3  7  8 12 0.4285714 0.6666667
4   4  8  7 11 0.5000000 0.6363636
5   5  9  6 10 0.5555556 0.6000000
6   6 10  5  9 0.6000000 0.5555556
7   7 11  4  8 0.6363636 0.5000000
8   8 12  3  7 0.6666667 0.4285714
9   9 13  2  6 0.6923077 0.3333333
10 10 14  1  5 0.7142857 0.2000000
```

But what if there are 100s of columns that you need to iterate through? I'd normally use Excel or SQL to concatenate the code and drop it in my .R script, but it seems there must be a way to solve this with R.

Full disclosure: this question is related to a question on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/combine-multiple-boxplots-in-a-lattice/7309#7309) where I hacked together a solution that cannot be optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 5:14, c = 10:1, d = 14:5, e = 34:43, f = 56:65)

n <- ncol(df2)
s1 <- seq(1, n, 2)
s2 <- seq(2, n, 2)

df2[paste(names(df2)[s1], names(df2)[s2], sep="")] <- df2[, s1] / df2[, s2]
```

Comment: your edited solution is nearly equivalent to the for-loop I came up with. I'll update the performance testing later as well. Thanks! `cbind`ing the result object to itself will prove to be slower than your new solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? It avoids `cbind`ing the object to itself multiple times:

```
for (i in seq(1, ncol(df2), by = 2)) {
    df2[, paste(names(df2)[i], names(df2)[i+1], sep = "", collapse = "")] <- df2[, i] / df2[, i + 1]
}
```

EDIT: It looks like my solution is marginally faster than @djhurio's

```
> set.seed(42)
> df2 <- data.frame(
+       a = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , b = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , c = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , d = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ )
> 
> system.time(
+ for (i in seq(1, ncol(df2), by = 2)) {
+ df2[, paste(names(df2)[i], names(df2)[i+1], sep = "", collapse = "")] <- df2[, i] / df2[, i + 1]
+ }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   1.06    0.64    1.70 
> 
> foo <- function(df2) {
+ n <- ncol(df2)
+ s1 <- seq(1, n, 2)
+ s2 <- seq(2, n, 2)
+ df2 <- cbind(df2, df2[, s1] / df2[, s2])
+ names(df2)[(n+1):ncol(df2)] <- paste(names(df2)[s1], names(df2)[s2], sep="")
+ return(df2)
+ }
> 
> set.seed(42)
> df2 <- data.frame(
+       a = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , b = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , c = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ , d = sample(1:10, 10e6, T)
+ )
> system.time(foo(df2))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.73    0.85    2.57
```