# perform function on pairs of columns

Tags: r

I am trying to run some Monte Carlo simulations on animal position data. So far, I have sampled 100 X and Y coordinates, 100 times. This results in a list of 200. I then convert this list into a dataframe that is more condusive to eventual functions I want to run for each sample (kernel.area).

Now I have a data frame with 200 columns, and I would like to perform the kernel.area function using each successive pair of columns.

I can't reproduce my own data here very well, so I've tried to give a basic example just to show the structure of the data frame I'm working with. I've included the for loop I've tried so far, but I am still an R novice and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
# generate dataframe representing X and Y positions
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:200),y=seq(1:200)) 

# 100 replications of sampling 100 "positions"
resamp <- replicate(100,df[sample(nrow(df),100),])

# convert to data frame (kernel.area needs an xy dataframe)
df2 <- do.call("rbind", resamp[1:2,])
# xy positions need to be in columns for kernel.area
df3 <- t(df2)

#edit: kernel.area requires you have an id field, but I am only dealing with one individual, so I'll construct a fake one of the same length as the positions
id=replicate(100,c("id"))
id=data.frame(id)
```

Here is the structure of the for loop I've tried (edited since first post):

```
for (j in seq(1,ncol(df3)-1,2)) { 
  kud <- kernel.area(df3[,j:(j+1)],id=id,kern="bivnorm",unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
  print(kud)
}
```

My end goal is to calculate `kernel.area` for each resampling event (ie rows 1:100 for every pair of columns up to 200), and be able to combine the results in a dataframe. However, after running the loop, I get this error message:

```
Error in df[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Edit: I realised my id format was not the same as my data frame, so I change it and now have the error:

```
Error in kernelUD(xy, id, h, grid, same4all, hlim, kern, extent) : 
id should have the same length as xy
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you receive an error message?

Comment: Sounds like this question may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021657/operate-on-multiple-columns-at-once

Comment: @DrDom I get this message --> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "for (j in seq(1:ncol(df2)-1, by 2"

Comment: @Chase - thanks for the link; I'll give it a read.

Comment: @user1195564, Joshua Ulrich already corrected this sintax mistake in your post.

Comment: @DrDom - sorry I copied the wrong result. The error message I'm getting is Error in if (ncol(xy) != 2) stop("xy should have 2 columns") : 
  argument is of length zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a disclaimer: I have never worked with the package `adehabitat`, which has a function `kernel.area`, which I assume you are using. Perhaps you could confirm which package contains the function in question.

---

I think there are a couple suggestions I can make that are independent of knowledge of the specific package, though.

1. The first lies in the creation of `df3`. This should probably be
   `df3 <- t(df2)`, but this is most likely correct in your actual code
   and just a typo in your post.
2. The second suggestion has to do with the way you subset `df3` in the
   loop. `j:j+1` is just a single number, since the `:` has a higher
   precedence than `+` (see `?Syntax` for the order in which
   mathematical operations are conducted in R). To get the desired two
   columns, use `j:(j+1)` instead.

---

**EDIT:**

When loading `adehabitat`, I was warned to "Be careful" and use the related new packages, among which is `adehabitatHR`, which also contains a function `kernel.area`. This function has slightly different syntax and behavior, but perhaps it would be worthwhile examining. Using `adehabitatHR` (I had to install from source since the package is not available for R 2.15.0), I was able to do the following.

```
library(adehabitatHR)

for (j in seq(1,ncol(df3)-1,2)) { 
  kud <-kernelUD(SpatialPoints(df3[,j:(j+1)]),kern="bivnorm")
  kernAr<-kernel.area(kud,unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
  print(kernAr)
}

detach(package:adehabitatHR, unload=TRUE)
```

This prints something, and as is mentioned in a comment below, `kernelUD()` is called before `kernel.area()`.

Comment: @BenBarnes-thanks for your answer! I apologize for not being totally clear. Yes, I am using the package adehabitat. And your point#1 was indeed a typo on my part. I have tried including brackets for (j+1), and now get an error message: Error in df[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: My suggestion is `kernel.area(df3[,j:(j+1)],...` (the dots signify that the rest of the code is as you posted it). Using the example code from above, I still get errors, but they have to do with "relocations". If the suggestion isn't working on your actual data, then your `df` might not have the required structure.

Comment: Hmm, yes I'm using your suggestion with my data, and am getting that df error message. I'm fairly certain my dataframe is set up correctly - I've run the function on data like it with good results. Perhaps the error is a result of my print line, as kernel.area returns actually returns a dataframe...I do appreciate your response though!

Comment: @User, Can you subset `df` like `df[1:10,c(1,2)]`? If not, it is likely in an incompatible format. Also, it looks like `kernel.area` takes an argument `id`, which is not in your code above. Finally, when I loaded `adehabitat`, I was warned to "Be careful" and use the related packages, including `adehabitatHR`, which contains a slightly different `kernel.area` function. Is that package loaded as well?

Comment: Yes, I can subset the dataframe. And yes, I realised I had left out my id argument, but have since included it and get the same error message. I will check out the adehabitatHR package as well...I am not sure if it loads automatically. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @User, Thanks for your answers! If you have modified your code from what you posted, would you edit your question (including `df3<-t(df2)`) with a new section that reflects what you are currently trying and the corresponding error message?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code, and have put in the error message I am getting. It's bizarre really, I've used this exact function before and have had good results, but now even when I try it with a subset of my current dataframe (ex df3[,1:2]), I am getting this error.

Comment: Just thought of something - it may be that I have to calculate the utilization distributions first using kernelUD. I didn't think kernel.area was dependent on this, but when I used it previously I also calculated the distributions first.

Comment: @User, I finally reproduced your error after adding an appropriate `id`. The error arises when `kernel.area` calls `kernelUD`, which you noted in the comment above. The source of the problem is pretty clear when you examine the function code, but it's not clear why the function was written that way to begin with. Please see my edit in the answer and consider switching to `adehabitatHR`!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Ben - you have been so helpful. Just ran the code, and seems to work wonderfully. adehabitatHR seems much better than adehabitat - no pesky id field!